# Cookie not persistent on page reload

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm trying to have a page reload after a record is deleted, but keep a "Deletion successful" message. I'm using jquery.cookie.js plugin to set the cookie and that works, but when I do a window.location.reload(true) the cookie no longer has a value.

Here is the jquery code:

```
function delete_user_data () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {task: 'delete_user_data',
                id: $('#subscriber').val()}
        })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log("success");
        $('#response').val(response);
        $.cookie('response',response, { expires: 1 });
        console.log($.cookie('response'));
        window.location.reload(true);
        var saved_response = $.cookie('response');
        console.log(saved_response);
        $('#response').val(saved_response);



    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });

}
```

Comment: And how are you checking the cookie on pageload ?

Comment: @adeneo I'm logging the cookie value to the console. See above.

Comment: But that's inside the callback for the ajax function, if you reload the page, shouldn't you be checking for the cookie on pageload ?

Comment: @adeneo I tried logging it in document.ready and it shows "null"

Comment: @adeneo On checking, I think that's the problem with the cookie. Now I'm closer to working this out. Thanks.